# How can I clear the hover and selection style of ListView in Xamarin.WPF

Tags: wpf, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is the XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"             
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App1.MainPage">

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TestList}" SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <ContentView>
                            <Label Text="{Binding TestName}"></Label>
                        </ContentView>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App1
{
    // Learn more about making custom code visible in the Xamarin.Forms previewer
    // by visiting https://aka.ms/xamarinforms-previewer
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = this;
            TestList.Add(new Test() { TestName = "aaa" });
            TestList.Add(new Test() { TestName = "bbb" });
            TestList.Add(new Test() { TestName = "ccc" });
            TestList.Add(new Test() { TestName = "ddd" });
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Test> TestList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Test>();
        public class Test { 
            public string TestName { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

The project above will cross-platform running both in android and WPF.

In android:
[image]
When the item is hovered, there is not any style for true.
When the item is selected, it will change the color into orange and I can change it by changing the background of the Label.

Well, in WPF:
[image]

When selected or hovered the item, it will show a blue rectangle that I don't need.

I don't want to show the blue rectangle while selected or hovered the item in WPF, that's why I ask the question.

I probably know I should set some property in the WPF program while I don't know which property I should set it.

Would you please help me? Thank you.

Comment: wpf: You can override the default template of listview, inorder to remove hover or selected backgrounds.

Comment: @neeleshbodgal I tried to override the listviewitem template in WPF while it no work. It seems the Listview in xamarin differs from the Listview in WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use Custom Renderer to achieve this effect.

define `ListViewItem` style in your `App.xaml` of WPF project:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="LvItemStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Border x:Name="border" Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="border"
                                                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="LightBlue" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="border"
                                                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="SkyBlue" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

then create custom renderer in Wpf project,`MyListView.cs`:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
using WpfApp1;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WPF;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.ListView), typeof(MyListView))]
namespace WpfApp1
{
   class MyListView:ListViewRenderer
   {
      protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.ListView> e)
      {
          base.OnElementChanged(e);
          foreach (var item in Control.Children)
           {
            if (item is ListView)
             {
                var list = item as ListView;
                list.ItemContainerStyle = App.Current.Resources["LvItemStyle"] as System.Windows.Style;
             }
           }
      }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this.

```
         <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

But it loses all default behavior. U can use triggers and visual states incase customisation is required like mouse over effects and so on.

Comment: ListView of Xamarin doesn't have an ItemContainerStyle property. I tried only to add the style into the resource of the WPF program and it still no work.

Comment: It seems the Xamarin.Forms version WPF is something different between the origin WPF.